# Making a drawable triangle wider - Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have this code in a drawable that builds a triangle. However I think the hypotenuse is too long compared to the width of the triangle. I'd like it to be like a equilateral triangle. How do I do this? Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-45%"
            android:pivotY="100%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"
                >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/loseBackground" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I've made this code to the background of a button.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/loseScreen"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_x="140dp"
        android:layout_y="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle_shape" />
```

Comment: why dont you use a `VectorDrawable`?

Comment: How do I use that? Would you mind posting an answer?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html

Comment: @OscarJohansson make screenshot I give better solution without see any `Image` I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

I found messing with rotated squares in XML to be a bit unpredictable for creating the triangles I wanted.  I made a custom view class which draws triangles based on the width and height you give it:

```
public class TriangleView extends View {

    public static final int UP = 0;
    public static final int DOWN = 1;
    public static final int LEFT = 2;
    public static final int RIGHT = 3;

    private int colour;
    private int direction;
    private Paint paint;

    public int getColour() {return colour;}
    public int getDirection() {return direction;}

    public void setColour(int colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
    public void setDirection(int direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }


    public TriangleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
        initAttributes(attrs);
        setupPaint();
    }


    private void initAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {

        TypedArray attrArray = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TriangleView, 0, 0);

        try {

            colour = attrArray.getColor(R.styleable.TriangleView_triangleColor, Color.BLACK);
            direction = attrArray.getInt(R.styleable.TriangleView_direction, UP);
        } finally {

            attrArray.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void setupPaint() {

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(colour);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(getTrianglePath(), paint);

    }

    protected Path getTrianglePath() {

        Point p1, p2, p3;

        switch (direction) {

            case UP:

                p1 = new Point(getPaddingLeft(), getHeight() - getPaddingBottom());
                p2 = new Point(getWidth() - getPaddingRight(), p1.y);
                p3 = new Point((getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / 2 + getPaddingLeft() , getPaddingTop());
                break;

            case DOWN:
            default:

                p1 = new Point(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());
                p2 = new Point(getWidth() - getPaddingRight(), p1.y);
                p3 = new Point((getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / 2 + getPaddingLeft(), getHeight() - getPaddingBottom());
                break;
        }


        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        path.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);

        return path;
    }
}
```

You also need to add the following to your `res/values/attrs.xml` file:

```
<declare-styleable name="TriangleView">
    <attr name="triangleColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="direction" format="enum">
        <enum name="up" value="0" />
        <enum name="down" value="1" />
        <enum name="left" value="2" />
        <enum name="right" value="3" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

You can then use this in your layout xml anywhere you want to draw a triangle:

```
<com.mypackagename.TriangleView
    android:id="@+id/loseScreen"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:triangleColor="@color/loseBackground"
    app:direction="up"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Remember to add the app namespace to your xml layout:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: no, no ,no, if you want a `Drawable`, create your custom `Drawable`, not a custom `View`, alternatively you can use a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class

Comment: The above has served me well but I shall certainly investigate the custom `Shape` class approach, thanks!

Comment: its an abstract class,  all you need is to implement  `draw` method

Comment: This is a little overwhelming to me. I don't understand much of that code. I was looking for something more simple. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I simply solved it by using this:

```
<TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="▼"/>
```

It works quite well. I might change it if I find a better solution.